# Record and Definition

Tags: coq

I have a question about the:  `Record` and `Definition`

I have this definition:

```
Definition rule := term -> term.
```

and I write a boolean function for it.

```
Definition beq_rule a b := beq_term a && beq_term b.
```

where `beq_term : term -> term -> bool.`

so my definition of `beq_rule` actually return exactly type of `beq_term` which is not what I want here. I want it return for me a type:  `rule -> rule -> bool.`

So I changed a definition of rule by `Record`:

```
Record rule := mkRule {lhs : term; rhs : term}.
```

and

```
Definition beq_rule (a b : rule) : bool :=
 beq_term (lhs a) (lhs b) && beq_term (rhs a) (rhs b).
```

My question is that:

1) What is the different between my first defined `rule` used `Definition` and another used `Record`?

2) If I want to define rule by `Definition` can I give an alias `lhs` and `rhs` likes in `Record` definition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your two definitions of `rule` are saying totally different things

```
Definition rule := term -> term
```

is defining rule as a type (or `Prop`) alias of the function type `term -> term`.  Hence

```
Definition not_what_you_meant : rule := fun t => t.
```

will happily compile.

As to the relation between `Record` and `Definition`.  `Record` is just a macro that converts into an `Inductive`.  So

```
Record rule := mkRule {lhs : term; rhs : term}.
```

is the same as

```
Inductive rule := mkRule : term -> term -> rule.
```

plus accessor functions

```
Definition lhs (r : rule) : term := 
 match r with
  mkRule l _ => l
 end.

etc.
```

You should think of `Inductive` as being fundamentally different from `Definition`.  `Definition` defines an *alias*.  Another way f saying this is `Definition`s are "referentially transparent", you can (up to variable renaming) always substitute the right hand side of a definition for any occurrence of its name.

`Inductive` on the other hand defines type (elements of Coqs universes) by listing off a set of constructors.  In more logical way of thinking, `Inductive` defines a logical proposition in terms of its elimination/introduction rules in a way that ensures "harmony".